# #1054 - La columna 'clientes.códigocliente' en field list es desconocida

Tags: mysql

Estoy aprendiendo INNER JOIN en tablas con mysql (en pildoras informaticas). El problema que tengo es que no me reconoce la columna que quiero consultar.

El código de la consulta:

```
SELECT clientes.códigocliente, población,númerodepedido, pedidos.CÓDIGOCLIENTE, FORMADEPAGO FROM clientes inner join pedidos on clientes.CÓDIGOCL=pedidos.códigocliente where población="madrid"
```

Y el error:

> #1054 - La columna 'clientes.códigocliente' en field list es desconocida

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y como se llama la columna? códigocliente o CÓDIGOCL?

Comment: Ejecuta un `SHOW CREATE TABLE clientes;` y un `SHOW CREATE TABLE pedidos;` y agrega el resultado a la pregunta pulsando en [edit]. Te recomendaría que evites acentos y caracteres especiales en tus nombres de base de datos / tablas / columnas. Si no hilas fino con la codificación el código podría fallar gravemente en varios puntos.